# AC_CHECK_LIB does not find library but compilation runs anyway

Tags: shared-libraries, autotools, autoconf

I am adding autotool support to a library project. It relies on another self-written library which is not necessarily in a default library path. So I will set LDFLAGS when configuring.

Nevertheless, I want to check for the library in order to warn the user to set LDFLAGS correctly. Therefore I put in this line:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([foo], [foo_func],
         [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_FOO, [1],
                     [Define if you have libfoo])],
         [AC_MSG_WARN([libfoo not found.])])
```

Now, if I do not set LDFLAGS, the check fails as expected and the warning is printed. BUT: When I run `make`, the code compiles nevertheless, because I have the library path set in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I find this confusing... I would want either the check to fail **and** the code not to compile or the check does not fail **and** the code compiles.

Am I misunderstanding what AC_CHECK_LIB means or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What this `AC_CHECK_LIB` seems to mean to me is that `libfoo` is _optional_ and the code can be built with or without it (`HAVE_FOO` is not defined, the code will "work around" not having `libfoo`).  If `libfoo` is really _required_ it should error out instead of warning.

Answer (score 1):

`AC_CHECK_LIB` does not care what conclusions you attach to the presence or absence of the library. It just determines whether the library is there and executes its third argument if so, and its fourth argument if not.

So getting the logic you want is up to you. If you replace `AC_MSG_WARN` by `AC_MSG_ERROR` in the fourth argument, as ldav1s suggests in the comment, then the configure script will abort if the check fails, and the code will not compile.

Comment: That's clear... But the library is found by GCC, while AC_CHECH_LIB fails. That is what bothers me. An error would be a false negative.

Comment: Oh, I see what the question is now. Then this answer is likely not very useful.